# Virus (Html.Exploit.CVE_2017_8750-6336209-0) in Angular4 vendor.js

Tags: angular, antivirus, virus

I am a bit confused, because i cant upload (sience 4 or 5 Days) any more, any of my angular4 projects. The Server run CalmAV AntiVirus and reject the vendor.js file with message:

> mod_clamav/0.11: Virus 'Html.Exploit.CVE_2017_8750-6336209-0' found in
>   '/www/htdocs/wxxxxx/build/vendor.js'

When i try to send that file with Thunderbird (my email client) i get a securety message to "can not send mail".

But i am sure that i have no virus. Because its every time only THIS file. I Deep Scan all my Computers. (MacOS Work Computer, Media Center Win10 Computer and today on the Office Computer (windows10) to.

As you all know is the vendor.js generated by the compiler when i run `ng build` or on my Ionic3 Project `ionic build`.

Is there any danger code maybe in any Angular Core file, that this CalmAV detect as virus? On Google only 2 Results to that virus: https://www.google.de/search?q=Html.Exploit.CVE_2017_8750-6336209-0&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE730DE730&oq=Html.Exploit.CVE_2017_8750-6336209-0&aqs=chrome..69i57.342j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Both are 2 Days old. So i think this must be a bug in CalmAV in last release.

Anyone Any idea?

best regards!

Comment: What happens when you upload that file to virustotal.com?

Comment: I doubt that this has anything to do with Angular itself.

Comment: @GSerg: https://i.imgur.com/OtKkjON.png

Again only CalmAV find it.

Comment: Try submitting it to ClamAV [as a false positive](https://www.clamav.net/reports/fp).

Comment: i did it. But another strange thing is. when i delete the dist folder, and scan the folder again with CalmAV, then he dont find any Virus... After ng build again virus alarm...

Comment: Got it... It was @agm/core. A Package with that you can place google maps inside your Angular App.